# Remove dtype datetime NaT

Tags: python, pandas

I am preparing a pandas df for output, and would like to remove the NaN and NaT in the table, and leave those table locations blank.  An example would be

```
mydataframesample 

col1    col2     timestamp
a       b        2014-08-14
c       NaN      NaT
```

would become

```
col1    col2     timestamp
a       b        2014-08-14
c
```

Most of the values are dtypes object, with the timestamp column being datetime64[ns].  In order to fix this, I attempted to use panda's `mydataframesample.fillna(' ')` to effectively leave a space in the location.  However, this doesn't work with the datetime types.  In order to get around this, I'm trying to convert the timestamp column back to object or string type.

Is it possible to remove the NaN/NaT without doing the type conversion?  If not, how do I do the type conversion (tried str() and astype(str) but difficulty with datetime being the original format)?

Comment: I don't think you can replace the datetime `NaT` as you've found, what is the problem with having `NaN`/`NaT`'s?

Comment: What do you mean by 'output'?  In some cases (e.g. saving to CSV) the `NaN`/`NaT` will automatically be filled with blanks.

Comment: I'm converting to html, and sending it as an e-mail.  Will the NaN/NaT still automatically be filled with blanks @chrisb?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This won't win any speed awards, but if the DataFrame is not too long, reassignment using a list comprehension will do the job:

```
df1['date'] = [d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') if not pd.isnull(d) else '' for d in df1['date']]
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
Timestamp = pd.Timestamp
nan = np.nan
NaT = pd.NaT
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': list('ac'),
    'col2': ['b', nan],
    'date': (Timestamp('2014-08-14'), NaT)
    })

df1['col2'] = df1['col2'].fillna('')
df1['date'] = [d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') if not pd.isnull(d) else '' for d in df1['date']]

print(df1)
```

yields

```
  col1 col2        date
0    a    b  2014-08-14
1    c
```

Answer (score 22):

I had the same issue: This does it all in place using pandas apply function. Should be the fastest method.

```
import pandas as pd
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')if not pd.isnull(x) else '')
```

if your timestamp field is not yet in `datetime` format then:

```
import pandas as pd
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')if not pd.isnull(x) else '')
```

Answer (score 3):

@unutbu's answer will work fine, but if you don't want to modify the DataFrame, you could do something like this.  `to_html` takes a parameter for how `NaN` is represented, to handle the `NaT` you need to pass a custom formatting function.

```
date_format = lambda d : pd.to_datetime(d).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') if not pd.isnull(d) else ''

df1.to_html(na_rep='', formatters={'date': date_format})
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is convert to a string:

```
In [37]: df1.to_csv(None,sep=' ')
Out[37]: ' col1 col2 date\n0 a b "2014-08-14 00:00:00"\n1 c  \n'
```

To replace missing values with a string

```
In [36]: df1.to_csv(None,sep=' ',na_rep='missing_value')
Out[36]: ' col1 col2 date\n0 a b "2014-08-14 00:00:00"\n1 c missing_value missing_value\n'
```