# Write out Date without time from excel file using Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, export-to-csv, datetime-format

I'm reading in an excel file and unioning it to a csv file.

When I read in the excel file I have a field of dates:

```
0    2018-05-28 00:00:00
1    9999-12-31 00:00:00
2    2018-02-26 00:00:00
3    2018-02-26 00:00:00
4    2018-02-26 00:00:00
Name: Date_started, dtype: object
```

I check the data type

```
df['Date_started'].dtype
dtype('O')
```

Then when I write out the resultant dataframe to csv I get this:

```
df.to_csv(folderpath + "Date_Started_df.csv",encoding="UTF-8" , index=False, na_rep='',date_format='%d%m%Y')
Date_Started

28/05/2018 00:00
31/12/9999 00:00
26/02/2018 00:00
26/02/2018 00:00
26/02/2018 00:00
```

> I have tried

```
df.loc[:,'Date_Started'] = df['Date_Started'].astype('str').str[8:10] + "/" + 
df['Date_Started'].astype('str').str[5:7] + "/" + 
df['Date_Started'].astype('str').str[:4]
```

Which gave me:

```
0    28/05/2018
1    31/12/9999
2    26/02/2018
3    26/02/2018
4    26/02/2018
Name: Date_started, dtype: object
```

I thought it might be in the writing out:

```
df.to_csv(filename, date_format='%Y%m%d')
```

but I still got the times!?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your series to `datetime` before sending to CSV:

```
df['Date_Started'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Started'])
```

This then allows Pandas to execute `date_format='%d%m%Y'` for the appropriate column with `to_csv`. The [to_csv docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) make this explicit:

> **date_format** : *string, default None*
>   Format string for datetime objects

Comment: my problem is that I've got fake dates in the list (e.g. 31/12/9999) giving an error "ValueError: Given date string not likely a datetime."

Comment: Yeh, that's a problem, one tip is to convert to a non-possible date, e.g. `df['Date_Started'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Started'], errors='coerce').fillna(pd.to_datetime('1950-01-01'))`. Works if you know 1st Jan 1950 is not a valid date.

Comment: would that leave blanks in the non-possible dates? As I actually need to be able to identify them as they are records without start dates

Comment: I was wondering if it was a writing issue as I managed to create "Strings", but times were added when it was written to csv

Comment: To leave blanks, use `df['Date_Started'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Started'], errors='coerce')`. Blanks will be `NaT`, also known as "Not a Time". Try it and see what happens.

Comment: I managed to get NaT, when I write this out is there anyway to write it out as something other than blanks? Baring in mind that I've got other blanks in the data set?

Comment: @REdim.Learning, Have a look here: [Remove dtype datetime NaT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141789/remove-dtype-datetime-nat)