# Pandas Replace is not working for me with 'NaT'

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having problems replacing NaT in my data frame and I don't know why. I've tried 'fillna' and 'replace'. For some reason both did not work. My last try is:

```
df['started'][222] = df['started'][222].replace('NaT', '')
df['started'][222]
```

The output is:

```
NaT
```

Looking at the type of data I'm dealing with, I see: `pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType`

What am I missing?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove dtype datetime NaT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141789/remove-dtype-datetime-nat)

Comment: `df["started] = df["started"].where(df["started"].notnull(), "")`?

Answer (score 0):

to replace value in df i always use this:

```
df['column name'] = df['column name'].replace(['old value'],'new value')
```